# Using Caliper 0.5 with instrumented code/JRE

Tags: java, instrumentation, caliper

Disclosure: I'm not super familiar with Java, so if anything rings untrue below, please point out

I'm trying to run some microbenchmarks with Caliper for instrumented code, with an instrumented JRE.

I set my `JAVA_HOME` to point to the instrumented JRE, (so that `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java` is appropriate). I setup various options using `$JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` (including a bootclasspath and javaagent).

I then run caliper as I usually would (which when using a non-instrumented JRE works fine), and I keep getting the following exception

```
An exception was thrown from the benchmark code.
java.lang.RuntimeException: failed to start subprocess
    at com.google.caliper.Runner.measure(Runner.java:278)
    at com.google.caliper.Runner.runScenario(Runner.java:229)
    at com.google.caliper.Runner.runOutOfProcess(Runner.java:378)
    at com.google.caliper.Runner.run(Runner.java:97)
    at com.google.caliper.Runner.main(Runner.java:423)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "java" (in directory "extra/"): error=2, No such file or directory
```

I've tried making sure the `$JAVA_HOME/bin/` is first in `$PATH`, tried symlinking `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java` to the current working directory, but all to no avail.

Anyone have any suggestions? I've probably spent upwards of 5 hours trying to work through this one...

[EDIT]

So I think this might be a broader question, focusing on the instrumented JRE. I ran a simple test, where I create a `ProcessBuilder` that just runs `ls`. It works fine with non-instrumented java, but fails with the instrumented version, with the same kind of error (`error=2`). Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm closing this question, since the issue was not with caliper, or broader instrumented JREs, but my own. For those interested, I had to chmod +x jre/bin/* and chmod +x jre/lib/*. Mmm seems I cannot close, so just gonna add this asn answer and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not with caliper, or broader instrumented JREs, but rather I had not `chmod +x jre/bin/*` and `chmod +x jre/lib/*`. After that, the issue was resolved.